# Redirect to home/index after logout using Grails

Tags: java, grails

I am trying to logout and redirect to the login page in my grails app.  I currently redirect to a "logout" page that says the user had logged out.  My login page is located inside a login folder.

How do I redirect after logging out to my login/index.gsp?

I've tried the following without any luck

```
render view: "/login/index.gsp"
render view: "login/index.gsp"
render view: "/login"
render view: "login"
```

Here is my controller:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class LogoutController {

    def logoutHandlers

    def index = {
        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }

    def page = {
        render view: "index.gsp"
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, SpringSecurity auto redirects to /login/auth after a I logout. I have the same LogoutController as you except I don't have the page = { } part. I only have an index. It should just work.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
render view: "/login/index"
```

Notice that you should never include `.gsp` in the view name so you will also need to change this

```
def page = {
    render view: "index.gsp"
}
```

Comment: When I do this, it just displays the login page on teh screen, but the url is now /logout/page... It is not the real login.  If I click the login button, I get 404 while it tries to reach /logout/login.

Comment: @C.Coggins you haven't shown the code associated with the login button, so I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

One, put a meta refresh header tag in your GSP to redirect the client to your login page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Two, upon logging out, redirect to your login page instead with a message that says "You are logged out, please log in again."